# jQuery validation error message positioning is odd

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently using jQuery validation plugin to validate my form field. When a user did not enter any value on the field, an error label will be displayed, stating that "this field is required". However, the error label is displayed all the way at the left side of the browser which seems odd. Here is a screenshot of my **problem**, the **desired** outcome and my **codes**

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1P6X.png)
[image]

[Desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNBCj.png)
[image]

```js
<script>
    $.validator.setDefaults({

        errorClass: 'help-block',

        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element)
                .closest('.form-group')
                .addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {
            $(element)
                .closest('.form-group')
                .removeClass('has-error')
                .addClass('has-success');
        }
    });

    $('#dataForm').validate({
        rules: {
            accountNameInput: {
                required: true
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

```html
<form id="dataForm" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="accountNameInput">Account name</label>
        <input type="text" id="accountNameInput" name="accountNameInput" class="form-control font-bold"
               maxlength="100" placeholder="Account name" value="" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: can you add your code in fiddle?

Comment: as it seems working https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/NzgPBK. There is some issue in your css

Comment: @BhumiShah What should I do to solve this problem? I found out that one of my Css file is having conflict with another

Comment: Add your css on fiddle, will check